# Excel VBA - Find cell and add to dynamic array

Tags: excel, vba

I have column C with the following structure:

```
[blank cell]
item1.1
item1.2
item1.3
Find1
[blank cell]
item2.1
item2.2
Find2
[blank cell]
item3.1
item3.2
item3.3
Find3
[blank cell]
and so on...
```

I am looking for a macro that finds let's say `"Find2"` and then adds all items above `"Find2"` (until the first blank cell is reached) to a dynamic VBA array. In this example, the array will have `item2.1` and `item2.2`. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: What have you tried so far? If you need a hint: use `Find` to find your expected value, then set your range and assign it to an array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this should work for you.  It's a relatively simple task, most of the code here is just error checking.

```
Sub tgr()

    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim rFindText As Range
    Dim rFindBlank As Range
    Dim rData As Range
    Dim aData() As Variant
    Dim sSearchCol As String
    Dim sFind As String
    Dim vData As Variant

    'Adjust these variables to suit your needs
    Set ws = ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet
    sSearchCol = "C"
    sFind = "Find4"

    'Find the text you're looking for
    Set rFindText = ws.Columns(sSearchCol).Find(sFind, ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, sSearchCol), xlValues, xlWhole, , xlNext)
    If rFindText Is Nothing Then
        'Text not actually found, error out
        MsgBox "No cell found to have [" & sFind & "]", , "Error"
        Exit Sub
    ElseIf rFindText.Row = 1 Then
        'Text found, but it's in row 1 so it can't have any data above it, error out
        MsgBox "[" & sFind & "] found but there is no data for it.", , "Error"
        Exit Sub
    End If

    'Text found and it's not in row 1, now find the first blank cell above the found text
    Set rFindBlank = ws.Range(sSearchCol & 1, rFindText).Find(vbNullString, rFindText, xlValues, xlWhole, , xlPrevious)
    If rFindBlank Is Nothing Then
        'No blank row found above it, assume the data starts at row 1 and set your data range
        Set rData = ws.Range(sSearchCol & 1, rFindText.Offset(-1))
    ElseIf rFindBlank.Row + 1 = rFindText.Row Then
        'Blank cell found, but it's immediately above the found text, so there's no data; error out
        MsgBox "[" & sFind & "] found but there is no data for it.", , "Error"
        Exit Sub
    Else
        'Blank cell found and it's not immediately above the found text, set your data range
        Set rData = ws.Range(rFindBlank.Offset(1), rFindText.Offset(-1))
    End If

    'To avoid an error populating the array, check if the data range is only a single cell
    If rData.Cells.Count = 1 Then
        'Data is a single cell, need to redim and then populate array
        ReDim aData(1 To 1, 1 To 1)
        aData(1, 1) = rData.Value
    Else
        'Data is more than one cell, can populate array directly
        aData = rData.Value
    End If

    'Array now populated with the desired data, do something with it here
    For Each vData In aData
        MsgBox vData
    Next vData

End Sub
```